# Angular2 named router-outlet link not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm having some trouble with my first attempt at using named, secondary routes. I'm following [these instructions](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#named-outlets) and integrating [this Tour of Heroes demo](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html) into [my app](https://github.com/dancancro/great-big-angular2-example/tree/heroes2). The main difference is that I've added the demo as a feature nested within a larger app. Instead of filling the named router-outlet with the appropriate component, the main page gets redirected to my not-found page.

You can see the deployed app [here](https://great-big-angular2-example.herokuapp.com/heroes/crisis-center). Click the Contact button to see what happens.

I have [this in my template](https://github.com/dancancro/great-big-angular2-example/blob/heroes2/src/app/heroes/crisis-center/crisis-center.page.html#L3):

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { popup: ['compose'] } }]">Contact</a>
```

and this in [my routing module](https://github.com/dancancro/great-big-angular2-example/blob/heroes2/src/app/heroes/crisis-center/crisis-center.routing.ts#L37-L39):

```
  {
    path: 'compose',
    component: ComposeMessageComponent,
    outlet: 'popup'
  }
```

The status bar shows that it's trying to route to

`http://localhost:4200/heroes/crisis-center/(popup:compose)`

Comment: Hey Dan! There are numerous issues with secondary outlets. You can read up about them here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues
Just search for "aux".

Comment: Hi Deborah :) Thanks. That's too bad. Routing has sure been a hard problem for team Angular. Didn't UI Router work pretty well? Are there many other gotchas like this? I'm just starting to dabble in React but I expect I'll have the same surprises after that investment.

Comment: I'm working on a Routing course now and only had significant difficulty with secondary (aux) routes (and fragments, but those are less useful).